# How can I import a word.doc into colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ms-word, google-colaboratory

I am new to python and I need a little help here. I want to import a word document from my google drive using google colab as a text document

I am a Newbie
imported my drive
imported my file Id

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that i misunderstand your question or not, but to bring the data files from Google Drive into Google Colab, you can `mount drive` in Google Colab. Here is a code sample :

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

after that, there will have a folder named `drive` appeared into your Google colab. Then, you can get your data that is kept in your Google Drive.

hope this help !

Comment: Thanks...like I said, I have done this already.. its the next step afterwards... thats crazy confusing

Answer (score 0):

We have to convert the `.doc` file to a `.docx` file ("manually" as in just changing the file name by adding `'x'`), then we can use `textract`'s `process` to read a word document `.docx` file:

```
!pip install textract
import textract
file_name = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/DATA_FOLDERS/WORD/SomeWordDocument.docx'
some_word_doc = textract.process(file_name)
```

`print(some_word_doc)` outputs:

```
b'Some text in a word document. This is the second sentence, and the last sentence.'
```

Comment: @Odiaka Olika does my answer work for you or is changing the file from `.doc` to `.docx` something you're trying to avoid?